# Set processor priority of PL/pgSQL stored procedures

Tags: linux, postgresql, plpgsql, scheduling

I would like to know if there´s a way to set a lower priority to a PL/pgSQL stored procedure when user calls it to PostgreSQL. When I call this procedure, the scheduler sets almost 100% of the CPU to the stored procedure I wrote, leaving other processes almost unattended.

System Info: PostgreSQL 8.3.11 on a Linux 2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.x86_64 box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to do, in a roundabout way.

Say your stored procedure is called `uses_too_many_cycles()`.  Let's write a `psql` wrapper script for it:

```
\set QUIET on
\set ECHO errors
SELECT pg_backend_pid() AS my_pg_backend_pid
\gset
\pset tuples_only on
\pset format unaligned
\! rm -f /tmp/renice_my_pg_backend
\out     /tmp/renice_my_pg_backend
SELECT '#!/bin/bash' ;
SELECT 'renice +19 --pid ' || :my_pg_backend_pid ;
\out
\! chmod +x /tmp/renice_my_pg_backend
\!          /tmp/renice_my_pg_backend

CALL uses_too_many_cycles();
```

We write a tiny shell script containing our desired command, and then we execute that shell script; we could not just execute our desired command directly, because `psql` treats everything to right of `\!` as a literal string.

---

#### General Caveats

- Playing with OS scheduler priorities can trigger unusual, and unpleasant, edge cases in behavior of server applications.  There is an element of risk.
- This trick attacks the symptom, not the cause; it should *not* be the first thing to reach for.
- "Technically possible" does *not* mean "advisable".

---

#### Specific Technical Caveats

- The lowered OS scheduler priority will persist for lifetime of the affected PostgreSQL backed process, unless you reset it.
- If parallel query is enabled, the lowered scheduler priority will *not* be inherited by any helper backend processes PostgreSQL spins up.
- Depending on your Linux distribution, `renice(1)` syntax may differ.
- This trick will only work if one of the following conditions holds:

  - executing OS user is the PostgreSQL user
  - executing OS user is `root`
  - executing OS user is privileged through some mechanism ( `sudoers`, PAM, ...) to `renice(1)` other users' processes, or anyway the PostgreSQL user's processes
  - wrapped in a `setuid`-privileged script

*Each of those conditions is operationally inadvisable, does not scale well, or both.*

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible.